# Does using the characters です at the end of a sentence make almost everything(depending on the sentence) sound polite?

Tags: spoken-language

For example if i say something like,"あなたはやさしい人です”。

Versus if I say,"あなたはやさしい人".

Is the second sentence (stated above) grammatically correct or does there "need" to be a particle at the end of my sentence?

I appreciate all the help I can get from you wonderful people.

Please give me your knowledge and help me better educate my self.

~A man seeking to improve himself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually three sentences worth discussing

> **(1)** あなたはやさしい人です
>
> **(2)** あなたはやさしい人だ
>
> **(3)** あなたはやさしい人

For each sentence, we should consider three dimensions: **grammaticality**, **softness**, and **politeness**.

(1) is **soft** (doesn't sound too direct), **polite** (shows respect for addressee).
(2) is **rough** (sounds like a point's trying to be made), **not polite** (doesn't show respect for addressee).
(3) is **soft** (doesn't sound too direct), **not polite** (doesn't show respect for addressee).

*All three* are **grammatical**.

(Note: "Not polite" doesn't necessarily mean "rude". There is no need to use the polite form with your friends, close family, or people much younger than you, for example -- in these cases the polite form would be overly distant or odd.)

(Note 2: It's probably worth pointing out that the presence of あなた makes all of these sentences sound a little jarring.)

Comment: Should this answer be qualified to refer to *spoken* sentences? I've never seen it written like type-3 and である is not mentioned.

Comment: All three can be written and spoken. In formal writing である is used, but in non-formal writing any of the three can be used (depending on desired effect). I did not mention である because it further complicates things by adding another dimension (formality) and I figured that it wouldn't be useful to the asker to start discussing more formal language.

Comment: I'm sorry to question you, but don't Japanese sentences need at least a verb to technically be grammatical? It might be acceptable/understood to leave it out, but I thought Japanese sentences were fragments without a verb.

Comment: @tabibito As far as grammatical analysis goes, such sentences are treated as having a "zero copula" (often denoted as ∅ in linguistics). That is to say, the sentence does still have a verb, its just that the verb's surface form is nothing. This can actually happen in English newspaper headlines: "Teacher credited with disarming gunman"; there is still an "is" in there semantically. In Japanese it is not limited to newspaper headlines of course.

Comment: Darius I greatly thank you for your input it helped me out in so many ways that I would run out space to describe on text. With this I also wanted to say that Kaizora also helped clarify what Darius told me because I couldn't understand (at the time) Darius' thought because he put it too intellectually but when things came together it all made sense. Thanks to you two I understand and to all the other people who helped me I love Japan and will continue to educate myself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Darius hit all the points on how it differs in spoken Japanese.

I'd like to add that **tone** and **context** also play a huge role when it comes to spoken Japanese, or any other spoken language for that matter.

Generally speaking, `です` at the end of sentence has a high likelihood of signifying politeness, but it also depends on context and tone (which I will only discuss context since I can't show you tone). For example, you see your friend picking up trash for a stranger who dropped it intentionally, and you reply:

`あなたはやさしい人（です）。`

It could imply a number of things, such as:

1. statement: "You are a nice person." (especially if you don't know this person very well)
2. re-affirmation: "You are indeed a nice person"
3. surprise, "Wow, you sure are nice."

could also be any combination of the inferred meanings depending on the situation. If sarcasm was intended though, `です` at the end would actually make it more informal and in some ways "rude." Plus, if you use `あなた` altogether, it could sound more impolite than polite.

Comment: This line *Depending on the tone, with or without です, it could imply a number of things, such as:* is a completely unclear utterance. Also,  I don't thin Darius was at all intending to say that adding あなた made the statement *informal*.

Comment: The point of that sentence is to indicate that in a spoken sentence, with or without です, it would not matter, because **tone** and **context** are also important factors in determining the meaning of the sentence. But you are correct, Darius did not imply informality in the sentence so I will not refer to him.

Comment: I think you're missing that I'm saying your sentence there is beyond empty, because it merely states that the presence OR absence of です can mean OR not mean any of a list of things that follows. In other words, it answers nothing to include such a sentence.